# Reindex array for cross correlation

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-image

I am trying to cross correlate a dataset with a checkerboard pattern but am running into an indexing issue.  The data comes from performing singular value decomposition on a nearest neighbor list, so consits of a 2D-array of positions(x,y) and eigenvalues (intensity). The xy part of the data is indexed in a way that does not follow the typical numpy image structure. I need to reindex the data arrays before I can cross correlate, but I do not know the correct method.
Here is an example:

[image]

The top left would be the data. Imagine that it is an "image" made from a scatter plot with assigned intensities (ex. `plt.scatter(x,y,c=eigenvalue)` ).  The bottom left shows how both data arrays would be indexed, in a "diagonal" manner.  The top right is the checkerboard pattern I would like to use for template matching. The bottom right is the indices for the checkerboard, which follow the typical "x, y" ordering.  Before cross correlation of the checkerboard with the eigenvalues, the indexing scheme must match.

Any help is much appreciated,

Eric

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.  I used

```py
np.lexsort((x,y))
```

then used the new index array to order both data sets.